# Check if a variable is null without warnings

Tags: php, wordpress, xdebug

In a PHP if statement, I want to check if a variable is null:

```
if (!is_null($datos))
```

The check is successful but I get a warning from xdebug:

[image]

How can I check the variable with no warnings?

Comment: try isset() instead od is_null()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`isset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to ensure the variable exists:

```
if(isset($datos)){...}
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: If variable `is set` - it is 100% __not null__. So second check is __redundant__.